# Adding Pop-Up to Event in Fullcalendar API

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using the version 3.4.0 of fullcalendar and am trying to create a pop-up when I click on an event on the calendar. I've tried lots of different methods, but don't really understand the coding well enough in a lot of the tutorials I've found and nothing seems to work. I've tried using this:

```
    eventClick: function(event) {
// opens events in a popup window
$('#popup').html('<iframe src="'+event.url+'" width="700" height="600"></iframe>');
$('#popup').dialog({autoOpen: false, modal: true, width: 750, height: 675});
return false;
   },
```

with a pop-up div identified in the body of the page, but I'm not sure what I have to add to this to make it work properly? All I want the pop-up to say is 'Under Construction'.

Thanks for any help, I'm really new to coding.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you copy the css, html, js basically you change the text in the modal-content class check the documentation below for more examples.

```html
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Under Construction</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp